# Separate the integers from a string

Tags: c++

i have a program which is uncompressing text files. If the input is 4A it should print "AAAA". My problem is when i am trying to separate the integers contained in the string, because after the program reads 3 numbers it seems to be getting into an infinite loop. this is my code:

```
while (getline(cin, line)){
    for(i = 0; i<line.length(); i++) {
        char * x = &line.at(i);
        if(isdigit(line.at(i))){
           counter = atoi (x);
        }
       ...............
 **Do Something**
```

I tried to print the char x as soon as it gets a value but as i said after it reads 3 numbers it's getting into an infinite loop.
Please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: That's not your code.   That's your summary of what you think is causing the problem - which is not the same thing.    Try providing actual code, which others can use to recreate your symptom, in the form of an [mcve].   Also provide a sample of data that triggers the symptom with that code.

Comment: Are you aware that `atoi()` processes as long characters as they are digits (i.e. it stops at first non-digit which includes terminating `\0`). Please, think about the following cases: "12A" (compressed from "AAAAAAAAAAAA"), "35A" (compressed from "555A"), and finally "35". The latter could possibly force `atoi()` to read after buffer end if `line` is of type `std::string`. AFAIK, you cannot count on that internal buffer of `std::string` is terminated by `\0`. (For this grant, `std::string::c_str()` exists.)

Comment: An example that triggers the the symptom is this "2a3c2b". When i am using as input 3a it prints aaa, then hitting enter and putting a different value lik 2c it prints cc. Although when i am using a string as an input like this "2a3b" it prints "aa". And finally inputting this string "2a3c2b" goes into and infinite loop.

Comment: @Scheff std::string guarantees that you can index one after the last char and that it's always zero.

Comment: @lorro I just had a look into [cppreference - std::basic_string::data()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data). You are right. It's granted since C++11 and my feeling seems to be originated from pre-C++11 times. (OMG, I'm becoming old...)

Answer (score 2):

You are using the variable i in the inner second for loop(which resets the value of i) hence the infinite loop.

Comment: Oh my. Thanks a lot mate. Didn't notice that at all!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version w/o hand-written loops, using regex & string view:

```
static const std::regex expr{ "(\\d)*[a-zA-Z]" }; // zero or more digits + letter

std::string uncompress(std::string_view const& input)
{
    char what{ '\0' };
    unsigned long rep{ 1 };

    if (std::regex_match(input.begin(), input.end(), expr))
    {
        char *end = const_cast<char*>(&input.back()) - 1;
        rep       = 1 == input.size() ? 1 : strtoul(input.data(), &end, 10);
        what      = input.back();
    }

    return std::string(rep, what);
}
```

In the [<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JddErDDA0YsYR1QP), minor modifications allow calling this while searching your input. Input sanitization is also showcased.